# How to assign fields in subclass to superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class that I want to store as an object in a datastore.  When I do that, I get back a reference, that I want to associate with the object.  I have extended my class to create a class that includes the reference.  However, I then want to write the base object back to the datastore (i.e. without the reference).  I've tried casting to the superclass type, but this turns the superclass object into a subclass object.  I suspect I am going about this the wrong way - can someone point me in the right direction please.
Here are my snippets to help explain:

```
class MyClass{
    String s; //Value to be stored in datastore
    //.... other variables
}

class MyClassWithId extends MyClass{
    Integer id; //Reference to location in datastore
}

class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClassWithId withId = new MyClassWithId();
        withId.s = "String to be stored"; //Assume that this is added to the datastore
        withId.id = 123; //... and this was the id returned.

        //Assume there has been some update.
        //I now want to store a MyClass object in the datastore
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) withId; //myClass has fields s & id :-(
    }
}
```

Comment: `MyClassWithId` is *still* a `MyClass` object.  Depending on how you're storing it, you would do well to ignore certain fields if you don't want them specified by a specific subclass.

Comment: The object `withId` is always of type `MyClassWithId` and `MyClass` (because you used inheritance). A cast will only change the compiler's view of things, it will not actually change the type of an object (though it will change the type of a primitive). You can define some serialization method within the superclass that defines the exact (de-)serialization of the object. If you set this method `final`, you can guarantee that it cannot be overwritten. Maybe this helps?

Comment: You can save `withId` Object ans then retrieve it and assign it to `myClass`Object, then you can get the values `s` and `id` from it.

Comment: How are you writing to the datastore?  Are you using Hibernate or some other ORM technology?